# Showing Progress Bar Values

Tags: javascript, html, css, progress-bar

I've been trying to make a progress bar with a value in the middle with just html and css but I have no idea how to go about it. I need some help with integrating the given value into the bar so it shows the value in the middle.

My code so far is this:

```html
<progress id="file" value="80" max="100"> 80% </progress>
```

but it doesn't show number in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [W3Schools Custom Progress Bar](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_progressbar.asp).

1. Create an outer `div` as a container of the progress bar
2. An inner div `div` that shows the "progress"
3. Change the "progress" using javascript

You can try this:

```html
<div style="background-color: grey; text-align:center">
  <div style="width:25%;background-color:green;">25%</div>
</div>
```

You can add more CSS on outer and inner `div` to make it more appealing

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay, you can try this

```
<div class="progress-container">
      <progress style="height: 2rem;" class="progress-da"  value="80" max="100"></progress>
      <span class="progress-value">80%</span>
    </div>
```

css with sass:

```
.progress-container 
    position: relative

.progress-da 
    width: 100%


.progress-value 
    position: absolute
    top: 8px
    left: 50%
    transform: translateX(-50%)
    font-size: 14px
    color: #000
    font-weight: bold
```